# Rails - Storing route data in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model that stores a path in the database under a column named "link_path" - for example:

```
Model.first.link_path == /posts/1
```

(or, put another way, I am caching the controller/model_id in a database table so Rails doesn't have to build it from scratch.)

In my view, I would like to build up a URL using this path information - for example, http://www.mysite.com/posts/1

I currently have the following code in my view:

```
<a href="<%= "#{request.protocol}#{request.domain}#{request.port_string}#{post.link_path}" %>">
```

In development all works as expected both when using POW/Nginx and Webrick - e.g., the link builds up to

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/1).
```

However, in production, when I hover over the link, it shows correctly (e.g., mysite.com/posts/1)  BUT, when I click on the link, the '/' between .com and posts is strangely missing.  The page links to http://mysite.composts/1

Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: Two questions: 1 - why not simply use link_to instead of coding the a tag explicitly?

2 - What makes storing the path and using string interpolation to build your link better than calling model_url(item), especially given that your interpolation scheme is misbehaving?

Comment: Can't use link_to because the url is not actually being built from the Post model.  This is for a notification mechanism where the user is notified of an activity and each notification item links to the appropriate show page.  So, the notification could link to posts or messages, or something else.  That should also answer q2.

Comment: Ah ok, but you can use link_to without being tied to a model. consider: link_to('my text', 'my/link', {attributes})

Comment: Thanks BrMcMullin - I wasn't aware I could use the URL helpers without calling the model.  Since I don't need the weight of link_to, I ended up changing to url_for(model_instance.link_path) and that seems to work as expected.  If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Actually you should post the answer; finding and using url_for was your discovery, not my suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to BrMcMullin - I wasn't aware I could use the URL helpers without calling the model. Since I don't need the weight of link_to, I ended up changing to

```
url_for(post.link_path)
```

instead of manually building up using string interpolation and that seems to work as expected.

Comment: You should re-write this to look more like an answer, complete with sample code. It might help some one in the future, so having a clean answer is a plus :)